# How to select SQL results based on multiple tables and value separated

Tags: php, mysql

Table students

```
---------------------------------------------
- student_id - student_name - student_image -
---------------------------------------------
-          1 - Ana          - avatar.jpg    -
-          2 - David        - avatar.jpg    -
-          3 - Jasmine      - avatar.jpg    -
---------------------------------------------
```

Table courses

```
-------------------------------------------
- course_id - course_title - course_image -
-------------------------------------------
-         7 - Photoshop    - image.jpg    -
-         8 - Cinema 4D    - image.jpg    -
-         9 - Idesign      - image.jpg    -
-        10 - Illustrator  - image.jpg    -
-------------------------------------------
```

Table students_courses

```
--------------------------
- course_id - student_id - 
--------------------------
-         7 - 1   
-         8 - 2   
-         9 - 3     
-         9 - 2
-        10 - 3
-         8 - 1 
--------------------------
```

Code

```
<?php
$host_database = 'mysql:dbname=tablas;host=localhost';
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try{ $pdo = new PDO($host_database,$username,$password);; }
catch(PDOException $e){ echo 'Error al conectar: ' . $e->getMessage(); }

$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM courses,students 
        WHERE course_id IN (
                            SELECT course_id 
                            FROM students_courses
                            ) 
        GROUP BY students.student_id";   

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$students = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>

<table>
<thead>
<th>ID Student</th>
<th>Name Student</th>
<th>Course Title</th>
</thead>

<?php foreach ($students as $valor) { ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $valor['student_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $valor['student_name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $valor['course_title']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
```

Result:

```
+------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID Student | Name Student | Course Title |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
|          1 | Ana          | Photoshop    |
|          2 | David        | Photoshop    |
|          3 | Jasmine      | Photoshop    |
|          1 | Ana          | Indesign     |
|          2 | David        | Indesign     |
|          3 | Jasmine      | Indesign     |
|          1 | Ana          | Illustrator  |
|          2 | David        | Illustrator  |
|          3 | Jasmine      | Illustrator  |
+------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Like this result:

`+------------+--------------+------------------------------+
| ID Student | Name Student |         Course Title         |
+------------+--------------+------------------------------+
|          1 | Ana          | Photoshop,Illustrator        |
|          2 | David        | Idesign,Cinema 4D            |
|          3 | Jasmine      | Photoshop,Cinema 4d,Indesign |
+------------+--------------+------------------------------+`

Comment: are you even querying the database? Also, what problems are you facing?

Comment: Time to learn about the JOIN syntax [try here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm)

Comment: Joins will do the trick

Comment: And probably [GROUP_CONCAT() as well](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: How do i do? @RiggsFolly

Comment: try this *SELECT students.student_id, student_name, GROUP_CONCAT(courses.course_title) as course_title 
FROM students 
JOIN students_courses 
ON students_courses.student_id = students.student_id 
JOIN courses 
ON courses.course_id = student_courses.course_id
group by students_courses.student_id*

Comment: @JYoThI not working

Comment: not working means ? is there any error ? @bdroid

Comment: Its work Thank you @JYoThI you missed letter s on student_courses is students_courses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use table joining in this case. Try this SQL query-

```
SELECT students.student_id, student_name, GROUP_CONCAT(courses.course_title) as course_title
FROM students JOIN students_courses ON students_courses.student_id = students.student_id
JOIN courses ON courses.course_id = students_courses.course_id
GROUP BY students.student_id
```

**Update:** In this table schema `NATURAL JOIN` should also work fine in mySQL.

```
SELECT student_id, student_name, GROUP_CONCAT(course_title) as course_title
FROM students NATURAL JOIN students_courses NATURAL JOIN courses
GROUP BY students.student_id
```

Comment: And `GROUP_CONCAT` to get the `Course Title` with all the courses a student is doing on the same line

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've tried it like this and nothing comes out ( SELECT student_id, student_name, GROUP_CONCAT(courses.course_title) AS course_title
FROM students JOIN students_courses ON students_courses.student_id = students.student_id 
JOIN courses ON courses.course_id = student_courses.course_id)

Comment: `#1052 - Column 'student_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: Resolved like this `students.student_id`, please see the updated answer

Comment: you have missed you add letter s on students_courses